Flutter Firebase Notification Intigration - dart pub global activate flutter_cli fails
I want to integrate the Firebase Push Notification in my Flutter App.
flutter --version
Flutter 3.24.3 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 2663184aa7 (7 weeks ago) • 2024-09-11 16:27:48 -0500
Engine • revision 36335019a8
Tools • Dart 3.5.3 • DevTools 2.37.3

Running dart pub global activate flutter_cli fails with the following:
The current Dart SDK version is 3.5.3.

Because pub global activate depends on flutter_cli any which doesn't support null safety, version solving failed.

The lower bound of "sdk: '>=2.0.0-dev.68.0 <3.0.0'" must be 2.12.0 or higher to enable null safety.
For details, see https://dart.dev/null-safety


As the error said, flutter_cli need null safety support. To enable null safety you should update your minimum sdk to 2.12.0. Open your pubspec.yaml then set the sdk constraints to:
environment:
  sdk: '>=2.12.0 <3.0.0'

From official documentation:

From Dart 2.12 to 2.19, you need to enable null safety. You cannot use
null safety in SDK versions earlier than Dart 2.12.
To enable sound null safety, set the SDK constraint lower-bound to a
language version of 2.12 or later.

Reference: Sound null safety | Dart
